# Can a thread be assigned to multiple processes on windows?

Tags: multithreading

I know that a process has at least one thread. But can one thread be assigned to multiple processes on Windows?

Comment: No. And what would be the purpose of doing so?

Comment: Why does this not work? There is no purpose of doing so, because it's a question from an exercise sheet. I know that threads are "inside" a process. From the point of shared memory of the threads within a process it might be impossible to have threads sharing memory with multiple processes. What's that? It does not make any sense ... :-)

Comment: You didn't ask about *sharing memory between processes or threads*. You asked about assigning *the same thread to multiple processes*, which is a totally different question. The answer to the question you asked is still **No**, one thread can **not** be assigned to multiple processes (and there would be *absolutely no value* in doing so).

Comment: Yes, I know that this cannot be done. And I tried to explain this with the memory access of threads: they can use the whole memory of the process. But if a thread belongs to multiple processes then this thred needs to access the memory of multiple processes. And how should that go (without IPC). Because the exercise told me to explain my answer.

Comment: The question itself is weird. It assumes that you can somehow assign a thread to a process in the first place and asks if you can do it for multiple processes. One cannot "assign" a thread to anything.

Comment: If your question is about sharing memory between processes, you should rewrite it to ask that question.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a practical programming question, so voting to close as off-topic.